# What does 'edge environments' in prisma document mean?

Tags: prisma

I'm new to Prisma ORM and when i read official document, it has some comparison between declare instance in PrismaClient instance.

URL : https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client#3-importing-prisma-client

What is difference between edge environment and normal import? And what does edge environment mean in this document?

I just guessing if it's meaning like AWS Lambda or something.Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a specific build of the PrismaClient, designed to be compatible with Vercels (the organization behind NextJS etc.) edge environment

> Then, navigate to lib/prisma and update Prisma Client’s import from @prisma/client to @prisma/client/edge to be make it compatible with edge environments:

https://www.prisma.io/blog/database-access-on-the-edge-8F0t1s1BqOJE